# Find word with maximum number of occurrences

Tags: algorithm, find

What is the most optimal way (algorithm) to search for the word that has the maximum number of occurrences in a document?

Comment: Maximum number of occurrences of what?

Comment: maximum number of occurrences of a **word** in that document

Comment: Are you looking for the word that occures the most in the document? a simple histogram will do the trick in O(n).

Comment: You should also elaborate what is "most efficient" most assume usually you mean fastest average case, but it also might mean 'less space consuming', fastest worst case, simplest to code....

Comment: optimal in the sense of time and memory. i'm fine with options which have a trade-off between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the word that occures most times in a document can be done in O(n) by a simple [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) [hash based]:

```
histogram <- new map<String,int>
for each word in document: 
   if word in histogram:
      histogram[word] <- histogram[word] + 1
   else:
      histogram[word] <- 1
max <- 0
maxWord<- ""
for each word in histogram:
  if histogram[word] > max:
     max <- histogram[word]
     maxWord <- word
return maxWord
```

This is O(n) solution, and since the problem is clearly Omega(n) problem, it is optimal in terms of [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Optimal expected-case, anyway.

Comment: A [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) instead of a hash map gives deterministic O(n) worst-case, but is likely to be slower in practice.

Answer (score 2):

1. Scan the document once, keeping a count of how many times you have seen every unique word (perhaps using a hashtable or a tree to do this).
2. While performing step 1, keep track of the word that has the highest count of all words seen so far.